# Requesting techniques for real-time video surveillance program developing

Tags: c#, image-processing, video-processing

I am developing programs using c# which associate with real-time surveillance, much like a research.

I do not plan to use libraries such as opencv or emgu...etc, cause in some circumstances I need to make detailed adjustment of pixels or do process after accessing all the pixels.

Right now my algorithms are basically using `Lockbits` and `UnlockBits` to copy pixels value into a two-dimention byte array, then I can do any process I want retrieving data from that byte array.

For that array, I declare it with a self-define structure:

```
struct Pixel
{
  Byte B;
  Byte G;
  Byte R;
}
```

so when I process a RGB bitmap I can simply use: `bmp[i,j].R, bmp[i,j].G, bmp[i,j].B` to access RGB values respectively.

However, this method causes great processing time I guess, when the resolution of the bitmap is huge, For my experience, 320x240 is fine, but when I process 704x480, the whole system just stuck.

I am wondering is there any other way to access all the pixels at a time that is faster then mine, or there is another technique to do real-time video surveillance?

Thanks

Comment: OpenCV does allow you to make adjustments of individual pixels. You'd be much better going with a package that has already optimized these techniques so you can focus on writing methods to handle the pieces it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much to talk about here...

1) As you said, pin it in memory then access it via pointer, rather than checked data structures like .NET array.

2) Consider transposing/preprocessing the data, if you are accessing it in a specific pattern. Bitmaps are normally stored in memory by row, but if you're accessing by column, performance will drop. If you need to access by column, or one channel at a time, for example, rotate the image or separate the channels before processing.

3) Make your pixel processing code efficient.

4) Parallelize (if possible).

5) Use a GPU :-)

There are nice OpenCV wrappers in .NET. [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is one of them, and offers CUDA support in its free version.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you do.

FIrst, unsafe code and a pointer is a faster way to access. Can be significantly faster.

Second, depending what you DO, load it into a d3d surface and use - directx.